# replace float nan turns 0s to nulls in PySpark

Tags: python, replace, pyspark

I had some values that were showing up in my PySpark dataframe as NaN, and found that I could convert those to NULL values. I was then adjusting those NULL values by imputing that value to something else. I found out while doing this that it is turning the 0s in a number of my columns to NULLs as well. Why is this happening, and how can I convert nans to NULL without affecting 0s?

```
cSchema = StructType([StructField("col", LongType())])
vals = [[0] for i in range(20)]
test_df = spark.createDataFrame(vals,schema=cSchema)

test_df.show(20)

+---+
|col|
+---+
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|
|  0|

test_df = test_df.replace(float('nan'), None)

test_df.show(20)

+----+
| col|
+----+
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
```

Answer (score 1):

The schema in your example is not suited for the operation you are trying to perform. You are searching for a float value in a column of (long) integers. I am surprised `replace` does not ignore the column altogether...
Here's what happens when you try to create such a DF outright:

```
>>> cSchema = StructType([StructField("col1", LongType()),StructField("col2", LongType())])
... vals = [[0, float('nan')] for i in range(20)]
... test_df = spark.createDataFrame(vals,schema=cSchema)
...
... test_df.show(20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "D:\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 748, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
  File "D:\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 413, in _createFromLocal
    data = list(data)
  File "D:\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 730, in prepare
    verify_func(obj)
  File "D:\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1389, in verify
    verify_value(obj)
  File "D:\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1370, in verify_struct
    verifier(v)
  File "D:\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1389, in verify
    verify_value(obj)
  File "D:\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1383, in verify_default
    verify_acceptable_types(obj)
  File "D:\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1278, in verify_acceptable_types
    % (dataType, obj, type(obj))))
TypeError: field col2: LongType can not accept object nan in type <class 'float'>

field col2: LongType can not accept object nan in type <class 'float'>
```

And here's what happens when you use an appropriate schema

```
>>> cSchema = StructType([StructField("col1", DoubleType()),StructField("col2", DoubleType())])
... vals = [[0., float('nan')] for i in range(20)]
... test_df = spark.createDataFrame(vals,schema=cSchema)
...
... test_df.show(3)
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
| 0.0| NaN|
| 0.0| NaN|
| 0.0| NaN|
+----+----+
only showing top 3 rows

>>> test_df.replace(float('nan'), None).show(3)
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
| 0.0|null|
| 0.0|null|
| 0.0|null|
+----+----+
only showing top 3 rows
```

So either try casting everything to float/double beforehand (if the nan-s are mixed in an integer column) or use the `subset` parameter of [`replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace) to specify only float columns to search in.